# How to manually set timepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I downloaded the timepicker from [here](http://haineault.com/media/jquery/ui-timepickr/page/). After cutting a lot of code I came to this simple example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQuery.timepickr.js</title>
        <link rel="Stylesheet" media="screen" href="reset.css" />
        <link rel="Stylesheet" media="screen" href="styles.css" />
        <link rel="Stylesheet" media="screen" href="../dist/themes/default/ui.core.css" />
        <link rel="Stylesheet" media="screen" href="../src/css/ui.timepickr.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.utils.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.strings.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.anchorHandler.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.all.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../src/ui.timepickr.js"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
              $('#timepicker').timepickr().focus();
              $('#timepicker').next().find('ol').show().find('li:eq(2)').mouseover();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body id="themeroller">

        <div id="splash">
            <div id="demo">
                <div id="d-demo-wrapper-1" class="demo-wrapper">
                    <input id="timepicker" type="text" value="02:30" class="demo">
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I noticed that when I try to manually set the time from the keyboard the numbers are changed automatically then the mouse is out of the input field. I noticed that even into the original example I cannot set the numbers manually. How I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the default value, by using `val` attribute in `timepickr`

```
$("#timepickr").timepickr({
            convention: 12,
            format12: "{h:02.d}:{m:02.d} {z:s}",
            rangeMin: $.range(0, 60),
            val: "02:00 am" //set your default time here
        });
```